# Conditional statement with unknown components

Tags: logic

Can there be a conditional statement where the truth value of both the antecedent $P$ and consequent $Q$ are unknown but the truth value of $P\Rightarrow Q$ is known?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @bounceback I think it's not possible to know the truth value of the conditional without knowing at least one of the components. This problem was in a textbook.

Comment: All sheep are animals. I don't tell you whether or not Dolly is a sheep (or for that matter an animal)...

Comment: Or consider a nonsense statement like '$x > 5 \implies x < 2$'. What can you say about the truth values there?

Comment: @bounceback That's a nice example although nonsensical. The truth value of the compound statement is false, where as a truth value for the antecedent and consequent doesn't make sense?

Comment: Well if I gave you an $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you would have a truth value for them. As it is, a priori you do not know

Comment: @bounceback Yes. Makes sense. Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in comments. To summarise:

Take $x \in \mathbb{R}$, together with the nonsensical statement
$$x > 5 \implies x < -2.$$

Clearly, the truth value of the conditional is known (it's false), but we do not a priori know truth values for the antecedent or consequent.

Try coming up with your own examples -- in particular, one where the conditional statement is true would be useful. Again, I hint towards this in the comments.

Comment: $x\gt1 \implies x\gt0$

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick. Start with a setup hypothesis like 'Let $x$ be a real number'.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot @bounceback